# Sync remote folders on Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, sync, incremental-backup

What is the simplest way to unidirectional incremental syncing of a folder present on a Linux system.

+1 for using the command line.
+2 for not using rsync (Seems to have some problems on my system.)

Comment: What exactly are your problems with rsync?

Comment: Since `rsync` very likely is the simplest answer, explain what problems you're having with that. (The problems may spill over to any other solution, anyhow.)

Comment: Necro, yes, but: sshfs may also work for anyone looking at this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[csync](http://www.csync.org/) is a file synchronizer especially designed for you, the normal user.

csync is a library and ships commandline client by default. It is server-less and allows synchronisation through either `sftp` or `samba`.

Usage examples:

```
csync /home/csync smb://csync:secret@rupert.galaxy.site/Users/csync
csync /home/csync sftp://csync@krikkit.galaxy.site:2222/home/csync
```

Comment: The `csync` command is provided by the `csync-owncloud` ubuntu package. (`sudo apt-get install csync-owncloud` `libcsync-plugin-sftp libcsync-plugin-smb` if you want them as well)

Comment: So this runs a one-time synchronization on demand. I haven't found any information on how to use this for monitoring and continually synchronizing a directory.

Answer (score 8):

I think you should solve your problems with rsync, that is the tried and true" syncronization tool for unixes.

```
rsync -uav --delete /loal/path example.com:/remote/path
```

*Note:* For bidirectional sync, you can use [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) as well as [csync](http://www.csync.org/).

Comment: +1, but this was only a partial answer for me. If you need to use `rsync` over ssh, use `rsync -uav --delete -e ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/dir /this/dir/`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do a unidirectional sync with bare tools.

At the onset, [**tar**](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html) the entire set of files and copy them to the destination point.
Also, setup a marker in the base directory.

```
touch /Source/base/directory/last-sync-time.txt
```

Now, we want to keep sync'ing from Source to Destination.

At the next time slot for syncing forward (from Source to Destination),

```
# The backup script
cd /Source/base/directory
tar cfj -N ./last-sync-time.txt backup.tar.bz2 .
scp backup.tar.bz2 user@backup-server:/Backup/Directory/
touch /Source/base/directory/last-sync-time.txt
rm -f backup.tar.bz2
```

1. The `-N ./filename` tells [**tar**](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC114) to archive only files modified or created after `filename` was modified/created.

   - Using a local reference for time confirms you make no mistake; if a backup was not taken for some reason, the next one will accumulate it
   - You can setup this script as a [**cronjob**](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) entry on the Source machine
   - I am assuming you will use `scp` with [**public key authentication**](http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/)
   - Also assuming you can reach the `backup-server` whenever this script is issued.
   - To be safer, you can add checks for confirming backup was stored and then, issue the `touch` command
   - You can choose to also insert commands to expand the backups overlaying them over previous ones at the Destination point; Or, keep incremental `tar.bz2` archives.

Answer (score 1):

I Use this short script for monitoring and continually synchronizing a directory with remote sftp folder;

```
#!/bin/sh
dir1=/home/user/folder
 while inotifywait -qqre modify "$dir1";
 do
    csync /home/user/folder sftp://remoteuser:remotepass@remoteaddress:remoteport/remotefolderpath
done
```