# Backup software in Ubuntu that can limit chunk size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

I'm trying to find a backup software for Ubuntu that will create backups in chunks for specified limit.

Think of it like splitting a RAR into multiple 50mb files.

I've tried *Back In Time* and *Simple Backup* but both are not offering that feature.

Can you recommend a program that does?

If there's no such program, perhaps even snapshot-catching backup script that does the same would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'd do,

```
tar cfj target.tar.bz2 [files]
split -b=BYTESIZE target.tar.bz2 splitpack.
# Note: the '.' at the end is part of my command
```

The files can be rejoined with,

```
cat splitpack.* > target-repack.tar.bz2
#   =========^= this is how the '.' works
```

Try this out and check with

```
diff target.tar.bz2 target-repack.tar.bz2
```

Do read the short manual page for `split` for its simple options.

Comment: I been trying this
tar cvj --listed-incremental fullbackup.snar /home | split -d -b 48m - /media/sdb1/full-backup/`date '+%Y-%m'`/full-backup.tar.bz2.split

It created the tarballs for me alright. But does it really give me incremental backup the next time I run it?

Comment: @GRex, For incremental backup with `tar` and timestamp data look at this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/6892/sync-remote-folders-on-linux/6907#6907, can be converted to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a tarball and then split it. see man tar and man split for more information. I recommend xz compression.

also there are rsnap? is capable of creating incremental backups with rsync, although for incremental I'd ask myself if a version control system might work.